# How to implement videojs-dvrseekbar plugin correctly?

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, video.js

I want to implement a videoJS player capable of playing live DVR stream. It should play the live stream but the user should be able to go back and watch like 30 minutes back.

I tried to use videojs-dvrseekbar plugin as shown in the following web page https://www.npmjs.com/package/videojs-dvrseekbar.

Like in the web page I tried the following

```
<script src="//path/to/video.min.js"></script>
<script src="//path/to/videojs-dvrseekbar.min.js"></script>
<script>
   var player = videojs('my-video');

   player.dvrseekbar();
</script>
```

I was expecting a video bar that you can jump back but It just plays it like a live video. For a reason that I don't understand, sometimes a short bar appears and you cannot move it. However today I was able to c\move it and DVR was working the only problem was it was too short. However, when I refreshed the page It disappeared again. I do not understand why any of these things happen. And there is not enough info on the plugin page. My whole code is as follows:

```
<video id="player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" style="width: 100%;" height="400" controls></video>

<script>
  var player = videojs('player');
  player.ready(function() {
      player.src({
        src: srcurl,
        src: 'https:..../Manifest.mpd',
        type: 'application/dash+xml'});

      player.dvrseekbar();

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Hello, @SelimEmreToy I just answered your question. You can check it. I believe that the last example is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello after searching through many pages I have found the answer. After the videjs 7.xx the dvrseekbar plugin functionality is added to videojs. You don't have to download or import an extra plugin for that.

It is explained here https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/guides/live.md

The new user interface is currently opt-in to prevent breaking backwards compatibility. We feel that the new user interface is much better and it will likely become the new default in the next major version. If you want to use the new user interface you will have to pass {liveui: true} during player setup. This can be done in two ways:

Using data-setup

Using the videojs function

var player = videojs('some-player-id', {liveui: true});
The new user interface shows the ProgressControl component on the control bar, hides the LiveDisplay component, and shows the new SeekToLive component when Video.js detects that the video that it is playing is live (via a durationchange event). Along with the ProgressControl update we also updated all the time tooltips on the player to indicate a negative number from the live current time, rather than seeking to a specific time.

Here is a simple example for you:

```
<link href="../dist/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="../dist/video.js"></script>
<script>
<video-js id="vid1" controls preload="auto" width="640"  height="264">
     <source src="https://akamai-axtest.akamaized.net/routes/lapd-v1-acceptance/www_c4/Manifest.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
</video-js>

<script>
    var vid = document.getElementById('vid1');
    var liveui = true

    if (videojs.browser.IS_ANDROID) {
        liveui = false;
    }
    var player = videojs(vid, {liveui: liveui});
</script>
```

However, when I tried I had many issues and it did not work as it should work. I also had to make some changes in css file.

However, I found a perfectly working example of liveui functionality. You can check it on here https://codepen.io/facundofernandez/pen/LmLPVW. And here is the code for that example.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" >

    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Videojs 7.5 liveui</title>


      <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://unpkg.com/video.js@7.5.0/dist/video-js.min.css'>


    </head>

    <body>

      <div class="container">
      <video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="870" height="364" ></video>
    </div>
      <script src='https://unpkg.com/video.js@7.5.0/dist/video.min.js'></script>



        <script  >

        let hls = {
      //src: 'https://d2zihajmogu5jn.cloudfront.net/bipbop-advanced/bipbop_16x9_variant.m3u8',
      src:
      "https://akamai-axtest.akamaized.net/routes/lapd-v1-acceptance/www_c4/Manifest.m3u8",
      type: "application/x-mpegURL" };


        let options = {
          liveui: true,
          //liveTracker: true,
          userActions: {
            hotkeys: function (event) {
              console.log(event);
            } } };



        videojs.log.history.disable();
        videojs.log.history.clear();
        let readyPlayer = function () {
          this.src(hls);
        };

        let player = videojs("my-video", options, readyPlayer);

        console.log(player, player.liveTracker, player.liveTracker.startTracking());

        player.on("error", e => {
          console.log(
          "error:",
          player.error().MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED,
          player.error().code,
          player.error().message);

        });

        </script>




    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Note that I was able to make it work with HLS stream. I tried many things but I was not able to make it with DASH stream

Comment: This working well for me, but the video start on current live. How can i start play the video from the beginning (begin dvr). Not from live?

Comment: So you want it to start like DVR but you also want to watch the live right? Or do you just want full DVR no live? If you want to first option I have not seen such implementation or someone who asks for such implementation. However, you might start as a regular DVR with a live button option. When the page loads it can start as DVR and when the live button is clicked you can just load the example above to create that illusion.

Comment: No, sorry. The problem i have is follow: As example my dvr store are 2 hours. If i open the player with live-ui the the player stream current live. Live button is showing red indicator. But i will play from dvr start (-2 hours).